# Creating a T-SQL temp table on another server machine

Tags: t-sql, temp-tables

I'm using SQL Query Analyzer to build a report from the database on one machine (A), and I'd like to create a temp table on a database server on another machine(B) and load it with the data from machine A.

To be more specific, I have a report that runs on machine A (machine.a.com), pulling from schema tst.  Using SQL Query Analyzer, I log into the server at machine.a.com and then have access to the tst schema:

```
USE tst;
SELECT *
FROM prospect;
```

I would like to create a temp table from this query window, only I'd like it built on another machine (call it machine.b.com).  What syntax would I use for this?  My guess is something like:

```
CREATE TABLE machine.b.com.#temp_prospect_list(name varchar(45) Not Null, id decimal(10) Not Null);
```

And then I'd like to load this new table with something like:

```
INSERT INTO machine.b.com.#temp_prospect_list VALUES (
    USE tst;
    SELECT *
    FROM prospect; );
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what temp tables are. They are only active for the current session.  Even if you could do it, I'm pretty sure it would not accomplish what you wanted.  Use a REAL table and then it makes sense.

Comment: I could use a real table as an alternative.  Is the syntax much different?  I thought to create a permanent table you would just use a table name that is not prefixed with the # symbol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to access a remote server in T-SQL is to fully qualify any table name with the following (brackets included when necessary):

```
[LinkedServer].[RemoteDatabase].[User].[Table]
```

So, for example, to run a SELECT statement on one server that accesses a table on another server:

```
SELECT * FROM [machine.b.com].tst.dbo.table7;
```